# Why is "IOUtils.copy(blob.getBinaryStream(), out);" not downloading, instead it display the image

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to download a file from my database using jsp and controller
Here is my code for the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dlFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        String idStr = request.getParameter("id");
        Long id = Long.parseLong(idStr);


        ImageUpload lr = (ImageUpload) service.get(ImageUpload.class, id);


        String dl = "image";
        Blob blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(lr.getImage());

        try {
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\""
            + dl + "\"");
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setContentType(lr.getContentType());

            IOUtils.copy(blob.getBinaryStream(), out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
}
```

Comment: You are missing `attachment;`  `response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=filename");`

Comment: @ScaryWombat It works! Thank you so much.